# How can I override username validation in Django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-registration

I have [a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) in my Django 1.11 site, along with [django-registration](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration).

On my registration form, I prompt for a username and passphrase. I have added MinimumLengthValidator and custom WordCountValidator validation to the passphrase field in settings.py (see below) -- these validation rules are rendered in the registration form automatically.

Now I want to change the username validation with three rules: length, must start with a letter, may only contain alphanumeric characters. I don't mind combining these into a single rule.

I tried adding [username_validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username_validator) to the class and setting that, but nothing happens -- probably because I'm inheriting from AbstractUser not User [(related 1.10 bug?)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27807).

How can I use my own validation rule (preferably  multi-clause) on my username field?

**Simplified appearance of form:**

```
Username: [     ]

Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.

Passphrase: [     ]

Your passphrase must contain at least 15 characters.
Passphrase must contain at least three words. Use spaces between words.

Passphrase confirmation: [       ]

Enter the same passphrase as before, for verification.
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 15,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'custom.validators.WordCountValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_words': 3,
        }
    },
]
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        user = super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return user

    ...
```

**validators.py**

```
class WordCountValidator(object):
    ...

class StartLetterValidator(object):
    ...

class AlphanumericValidator(object):
    ...

class CombinedValidator(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the `clean()` method of your `User`model and call your validators there:

```
def clean(self):
    # do some data-clean
    # maybe do a super().clean() here

    validator1 = WordCounterValidator(self)
    validator1.myValidationMethod()
    #...
    validator2 = StartLetterValidator(self)
    validator2.myValidationMethod()
    #...
    validator3 = AlphanumericValidator(self)
    validator3.myValidationMethod()
    #...
    validator4 = CombinedValidator(self)
    validator4.myValidationMethod()
    #...

    # maybe do a super().clean() here
```

To simplify your validation code, it might be useful to write validation methods instead of validation classes. But I think both designs will do.

## Update

*Extended answer for the question in comment, due to size of the answer:*

django provides [ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/) for this. If you want to raise multiple `ValidationError`s at once I suggest to use a dictionary to collect your errors:

```
err_dict = {}
```

Then simply add an error to that dict with the *field-name* as key and the *error message* as value: `err_dict["field-name"] = "Error mssg"`.

At the end of your `clean()` simply check your dict for errors with `if err_dict` (true if error[s] in dict) and raise those with `raise ValidationError(err_dict)`.

In your case you might want to do something like

```
err_dict = validatot1.myValidationMethod(err_dict)
```

to extend your `err_dict` (if necessary) with each validation-function.

Comment: great - how do I accumulate validation errors in this context?